# ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalyticsServices clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

```
Ld /Users/madhav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serra_Internationals-aivsdwufcxzcqjesbhanxgzjofsx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Serra\ Internationals.app/Serra\ Internationals normal x86_64
cd "/Users/madhav/Desktop/practice/Serra international Latest"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk -L/Users/madhav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serra_Internationals-aivsdwufcxzcqjesbhanxgzjofsx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/madhav/Desktop/practice/Serra\ international\ Latest/Pods/Google/Libraries -L/Users/madhav/Desktop/practice/Serra\ international\ Latest/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries -L/Users/madhav/Desktop/practice/Serra\ international\ Latest/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/madhav/Desktop/practice/Serra\ international\ Latest/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/madhav/Desktop/practice/Serra\ international\ Latest/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/madhav/Desktop/practice/Serra\ international\ Latest/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries -F/Users/madhav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serra_Internationals-aivsdwufcxzcqjesbhanxgzjofsx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/madhav/Desktop/practice/Serra\ international\ Latest/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks -F/Users/madhav/Desktop/practice/Serra\ international\ Latest -filelist /Users/madhav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serra_Internationals-aivsdwufcxzcqjesbhanxgzjofsx/Build/Intermediates/Serra\ Internationals.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Serra\ Internationals.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Serra\ Internationals.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/madhav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serra_Internationals-aivsdwufcxzcqjesbhanxgzjofsx/Build/Intermediates/Serra\ Internationals.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Serra\ Internationals.build/Serra\ Internationals.app.xcent -lz.1 -lsqlite3 -lGoogleAnalyticsServices -framework Accelerate -framework CoreBluetooth -framework Crashlytics -lc++ -licucore -lz -framework Fabric -lsqlite3 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenGLES -weak_framework CloudKit -framework ImageIO -framework GLKit -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreData -framework AVFoundation -framework GoogleMaps -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/madhav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serra_Internationals-aivsdwufcxzcqjesbhanxgzjofsx/Build/Intermediates/Serra\ Internationals.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Serra\ Internationals.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Serra\ Internationals_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/madhav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serra_Internationals-aivsdwufcxzcqjesbhanxgzjofsx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Serra\ Internationals.app/Serra\ Internationals

ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalyticsServices
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the library to embedded binaries in General Settings

[image]